# Easiest driver for a Linux Device Driver newbie

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I am new in Linux Device Driver Field. Can anybody tell which driver will be easier for me to understand among Audio drivers, Video Drivers, Camera Drivers, Power Management Drivers or Boot-loders? Please suggest me the driver which will be easy for a newbie. If you can suggest any good source for the same (not book...any online material if available) it would be great. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should start by studying the basics of Loadable Kernel Modules.
First few chapters of [LKMPG](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html) by Salzman will be a good start

And the easiest driver, IMHO, is a simpleton driver that uses memory as a device and reads/write to it. One such driver is beautifully explained in third chapter of [LDD3e](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

You would also need to increase your knowledge of the Linux Kernel itself in order to advance towards relatively hard drivers. The better you understand Kernel's subsystems the easier it will be for you to develop device drivers around them.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I have already gone through the resources you told. If you can specifically tell the one among the drivers asked in question then it'll be very much helpful.

Comment: Well it depends on the hardware/chips that you are trying to code the driver for and the protocol they work on.
I would opt for a USB camera though, as there is a lot of material on the internet about USB device drivers.

Comment: It will be easier to suggest if you tell us what kind of driver development work have you already done.